# unable to run "npm start" after installing bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I created the using "npx create-react-app " then installed bootstrap using "npm install bootstrap". After this, my code is unable to run and it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: readdirp: root argument must be a string. Usage: readdirp(root, options)
at readdirp (/Users/brianhsu305/Desktop/projects/portfolio/node_modules/readdirp/index.js:259:11)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/brianhsu305/Desktop/projects/portfolio/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:374:5)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/Users/brianhsu305/Desktop/projects/portfolio/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:428:18)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/brianhsu305/Desktop/projects/portfolio/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/brianhsu305/Desktop/projects/portfolio/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/brianhsu305/.npm/_logs/2021-03-22T21_30_28_033Z-debug.log

This is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "portfolio",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
```

}

any answer is appreciated, thank you

Comment: The error tells you what's going on `root argument must be a string. Usage: readdirp(root, options)`. Look in your code for `readdirp` and make sure you're passing a string as the first argument.